# Looking for an single byte encoding with grave=xC1 acute=xC2 cedilla=xD0

Tags: encoding, set, character, codepages

Having trouble finding a code page or other single byte encoding having accents in these positions:

grave in xC1  acute in xC2 cedilla in xD0

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any encoding that meets those criteria.

[ISO 6937](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_6937) is quite close. Would be surprised to see it these days though.

Comment: Thanks but as you point out its not exact. I have just found a match though ... ISO-5426 ... new to me.

Comment: Good catch. New to me too. Seems to share quite a lot in common with 6937.